# How to display different webpage depending on time of day? (Django)

Tags: django

I'm trying to build a food delivery website for group orders. The food is to be delivered at pre-set times of the day (ie 5pm, 8pm, midnight).

Let's say the cut off time for ordering a 5pm order is 4pm.  So at 4:01pm I want the webpage for 5pm orders to say "5pm orders not available", but if it's before 4pm I want the page to be the normal ordering page.

Would i include the logic for this in my "views" or "templates"?  or would you recommend using javascript to implement this functionality?

Comment: Either.  You can do this server side or on the browser with jQuery.  Pick one and if you have any issues post your code so we can help you.

Comment: I think you're always better off filtering in the view, then using the same template to render whatever data comes from your view (based on time of day, or whatever)

Comment: The javascript part would only be an add-on to the server-side part. Your view/template should still limit the functionality at the time its rendered. But the javascript part can be used to actively check the time if they are sitting there at 3:59pm and it rolls over. Then js can dynamically modify the display. If you didn't have the js part, and it rolled over, submitting the form would fail on the server because its now past your cutoff.

Answer (score -1):

One thing to note is that if you are using javascript the time will be specific to the client (user) and if you expect users from different timezones (which you should at least for good heuristics).

Javascript:

```
var hours = currentTime.getHours();
if(hours < 16 && hours > 8){//do something..
}
```

But probably best to get server time using PHP

```
$hour = date("H");
```

Comment: The OP is not using PHP. They are using django (python). And I think the javascript part is a little off topic for the question.